# How to show all items on click of button and show first item of the list for rich autocomplete in jsf?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

While i am using the rich autocomplete but the problem is while searching only it is showing the list of values if it is empty value it's not showing all values.I took ajax as mode.

Comment: can you brief your problem,because I couldn't get from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override this method of getMinCharsOrDefault of richfaces library from your local app with value = 0 and in facesconfig.xml add below renderer kit.

```
 <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
 <renderer-type>org.richfaces.AutocompleteRenderer</renderer-type>
  <renderer-class> your overriden class name </renderer-class>
```